# Regex for checking presence and absence of keywords in User Agent String

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a Regex in Javascript to sniff the User Agent string. Here is some pseudo code below:

```
is_not_tablet_bool = /android.+mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
switch(true)
{
     case (is_not_tablet_bool):
         return true;
     break;
}
```

I'm trying to craft a regex that will do something close to the opposite of the above i.e.

1. ensure that 'android' keyword is present in string, and at the same time
2. ensure that 'mobile' keyword is absent from string

Thanks for the anticipated assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Negative lookahead

Regular expressions have a construct called negative lookahead which matches a string in the regular expression without capturing the lookahead part:

Your regular expression should be written this way:

```
/android(?!.*mobile)/i
```

This will match any string that contains word **android** that is not followed by word **mobile** with ignored case. This also means that you can remove the `toLowerCase` call.

#### Addition: Negative lookbehind

In case you need only match those strings that have word **android** in them but lack **mobile** (either before or after) then a combination of negative lookaheads and lookbehinds will do.

```
/(?<!mobile.*)android(?!.*mobile)/i
```

But the problem is that **Javascript doesn't support negative lookbehinds**. So you have to employ a different trick that will help you determining that situation.

There are several possibilities of which following seem to be most interesting (and last one useful):

1. Replace a matching negative string that will fail afterwards:

   ```
   var nav = navigator.userAgent.replace(/mobile.*android/, "fail" );
   return /android(?!.*mobile)/i.test(nav);
   ```
2. Use two lookaheads. One on normal string and the other on reversed one while also having a reversed regular expression:

   ```
   var nav = navigator.userAgent;
   var after = /android(?!.*mobile)/i.test(nav);
   var before = /diordna(?!.*elibom)/i.test(nav.split("").reverse().join(""));
   return before && after;
   ```
3. Simplicity is key. Two simple regular expressions would do the trick just fine as well:

   ```
   var nav = navigator.userAgent;
   return /android/i.test(nav) && !/mobile/i.test(nav);
   ```

---

> ***Note:** I'm not sure whether your code is actual code, because if it is I would strongly recommend you reconsider the use of* `switch(true)` *statement and simply replace it by*
>   `return is_not_tablet_bool;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I think I'll go with simplicity (Door No. 3) as I'm not quite a Regex ninja yet. As to the use of `switch`, I'm doing multiple checks on the string but I want to return a value when something is true so I need to use the statement. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using regular expressions makes this task any easier.  I would simply check for the inclusion and exclusion of those strings using the [`String.indexOf(...)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```javascript
function isNotAndroidMobile(userAgentString) {
  var ua = userAgentString.toLowerCase();
  return (ua.indexOf('android')>=0) && (ua.indexOf('mobile')===-1);
}
```