# javascript reg pattern match css selector

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I want to try filter all selector using js reg.  Predict I want to match `div#abc.read-more`.(Please note that `div`, `#abc`, `.read-more` all can exist or not.But if div exist, it should be at the beginning). I list all situations I know in two array: matched and unmatched. Here's the [test code](http://www.bpaste.net/show/N912OjsUNmULl36rwJSH/) . I use **jasmine** test engineer.

The reg pattern I use now is `/((\bdiv)+|(\.read-more)+|(#abc)+)(\s*|(:\w+)+)\s*(((?=,)(.*))|$)/`

But there's still have two situations not being pass. `.read-morediv#abc` and `#abcdiv.read-more`. Common thing is `div` is at the middle.

Sorry, But I just get that there's two more situations will fail too: `div.read-morediv#abc` and `div#abcdiv.read-more`. These two both should be unmatched.

Anyone can help here? And I will very appreciate If you can explain how you get your solution. :D

Comment: Why are you doing this if I may ask? You should be able to use the DOM.

Comment: `#abcdiv.read-more` would match the element with ID `abcdiv` and class `read-more`. Is that really what you want? Type selectors must always be at the beginning: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax.

Comment: @elclanrs, what I plan to do is emulate devtool or firebug. user click one elemnt , then show all relative style to user.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes. I try to match selector. And some class like `.divider` will match `div`, right? I need to filter these out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For div.read-morediv#abc:

((\bdiv)+|(.read-more)+|(#abc)+) matches the final '#abc'

(\s*|(:\w+)+) matches the following 0 spaces (\s*)

\s* again matches 0 spaces

(((?=,)(.*))|$) matches the end of the string (via the |$)

The pattern for the other example is similar. In both cases, the presence of 'div' is entirely ignored in generating the match, because another part of the 3-part OR in the first group is sufficient.

Comment: yes, those case behavior as you said. Do you have any solution? So far, I still can figure out one solution for these situations. :)

Comment: Check out this question - I think it'll help. The negative lookbehind is really what you wanted here (to verify that div doesn't occur after the other two), but there are some workarounds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458946/regex-for-checking-presence-and-absence-of-keywords-in-user-agent-string